# Understanding Swing and repaint()

Tags: java, swing, repaint, paintcomponent

I am trying to understand how painting with Swing works. For that purpose I've been reading the Oracle tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html

My question is a simple one:
Why do the two calls to the same function (repaint) have different behaviour? How does it come that the UI Delegate paints the background on the previously painted rectangle, but paints a new rectangle on the new area? I don't see any particular reason on paintComponent() for that.

I have also read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html trying to understand the situation. It seems there is some connection to the opaque property of a component. Does this property change after we create a new rectangle, so that it is true (thus, as mentioned, the ui.update() will set it to the background color). How come it paintComponent() doesn't paint a new rectangle there?

Comment: search posts tagged by paintComponent and,or with repaint, Swing Timer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is called with different parameters:

```
repaint(squareX,squareY,squareW+OFFSET,squareH+OFFSET);
squareX=x;
squareY=y;
repaint(squareX,squareY,squareW+OFFSET,squareH+OFFSET);
```

In the first call to repaint() squareX and squareY indicates location of the previously painted object. In second the second call, squareX and squareY is changed to the current mouse location.

From [JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) API documentation on repaint():

> Adds the specified region to the dirty region list if the component is
>   showing. The component will be repainted after all of the currently
>   pending events have been dispatched.

That is, the first call to repaint() marks the previous location as dirty, the second, marks the current location as dirty. When the event (moveSquare) is completed, paintComponent is re-executed, and these two areas are updated. The red rectangle is only placed in the new location, the old location is updated to be "empty".

Comment: Indeed, but my question is, why does it get treated as such? Why does the first call repaint actually paint the background color, instead of just redrawing a rectangle?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, updated my answer to elaborate on what repaint actually does.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about [the opaque property](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#props), which is `true` for typical `PanelUI` implementations. In particular, [`paintComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) says,

> if you do not invoke super's implementation, you must honor the opaque property...If you do not honor the opaque property you will likely see visual artifacts.

Your code *does* honor the opaque property by invoking `super.paintComponent(g)`. *Both* calls to `repaint()` clear the drawing rectangle to the background color. Try setting a different background color in the `MyPanel` constructor and omitting the `super` call to see the effect:

```
public MyPanel() {

    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    setBackground(Color.cyan);
    ...
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    //super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawString("This is my custom Panel!", 10, 20);
    ...
}
```

Comment: When omitting the `super` call, whether I have set a background color or not, there is some dragging across the screen, since previous boxes aren't cleared (I guess that's because nothing but the new rectangle is repainted, and the previous paints still exist).
I have read that using the `setOpaque()` method isn't an ideal concept, since it messes with the original goal of the property, and results in bugs in Nimbus L&F, so I'm trying to avoid using that! I guess the `super` call is the best option.

Comment: Right, I though you were still unsure about the connection to `opaque`.